# Sinatra does nothing with requests from a phonegap application

Tags: ruby, cordova, post, sinatra

I have a simple sinatra server with a post block. If I send a $.post from a browser the server receives the post, but when sent from my phonegap application it does nothing, no error code or any output whatsoever.

I previously wrote a simple TCPServer#accept process, and since I was successful with that I proceeded to sinatra, but found the following:

This post works well in sinatra and with TCPServer.accept

```
POST /api/v/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localho.st:8015
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://api.jquery.com
Cookie: _fitter_session=[deleted]
Content-Length: 7
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1 Safari/601.5.17
Referer: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

The next one doesn't work in sinatra though it still does in TCPServer

```
POST /api/v/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localho.st:8015
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 362
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: file://
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-G900F Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US
Cookie: _fitter_session=[deleted]
X-Requested-With: com.myapp.myphonegapp
```

I think I am missing something obvious but can't find what it is, I'm searching in google but find no soluction or similar problem, any help is welcome

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
- I tried running a rails server and it receives the post correctly.
- This problem affects both get and post sent from the phonegap application.

Edit2:

Sinatra file:

```
require 'sinatra'
# require 'sinatra/cross_origin'

set :port, 8015
#set :server, 'thin'

post '/api/v/1' do
  puts 'it worked!'
end
```

Phonegap ajax request:

```
$.post('http://localho.st:8015/api/v/1', {
        test: 'foo'
      })
        .done(function(s) {
          console.log(s);
        })
        .fail(function(e) {
          console.log(e);
        })
```

If I run a node server and serve the application the request runs succesfully (with cors enabled in the browser) but on an android device, it doesn't, again, if I replace the sinatra with a rails in the same port, rails gets the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put in your code`set :bind, '0.0.0.0'`. I guess that your server is listening only on localhost.

Comment: Yep... you're totally right:

`String specifying the hostname or IP address of the interface to listen on when the :run setting is enabled. The default value in the development environment is 'localhost' which means the server is only available from the local machine. In other environments the default is '0.0.0.0', which causes the server to listen on all available interfaces`. (src: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html)

Thank you!